# print jwplayer module in a page from specific node

Tags: 6, theming, media

How can I print jwplayer from specific node in a page (Drupal 6)?

I'm looking for the php code and I can't use views here. I tried following codes:

```
$node= node_load(5);
print $node->field_video;
```

and

```
print theme('jwplayermodule');
```

http://drupal.org/node/1260116

I know those are wrong and I'd appreciate your help.